# How to improve time complexity of remove all multiplicands from array or list?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find elements from array(integer array) or list which are unique and those elements must not divisible by any other element from same array or list.

You can answer in any language like python, java, c, c++ etc.

I have tried this code in Python3 and it works perfectly but I am looking for better and optimum solution in terms of time complexity.

assuming array or list A is already sorted and having unique elements

```
    A = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
    while i<len(A)-1:
        while j<len(A):
            if A[j]%A[i]==0:
                A.pop(j)
            else:
                j+=1
        i+=1
        j=i+1
```

For the given array `A=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]` answer would be like `ans=[2,3,5,7,11,13]`

another example,`A=[4,5,15,16,17,23,39]` then ans would be like, `ans=[4,5,17,23,39]`

- ans is having unique numbers
- any element i from array only exists if (i%j)!=0, where i!=j

Comment: does your current code works? Seems like it takes `O(n^2)`

Comment: Your code seems to require a sorted list to be correct. Will that always be true?

Comment: Do you care about a fast solution, or about implementing an optimal algorithm yourself? These often aren't the same (in python)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yes it works and i want to reduce O(n^2). That's the question how?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes sorted list will always be there

Comment: How large can the integers be?

Comment: Can there be non positive integers?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more natural to do it in reverse, by building a new list containing the answer instead of removing elements from the original list. If I'm thinking correctly, both approaches do the same number of mod operations, but you avoid the issue of removing an element from a list.

```
A = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
ans = []
for x in A:
    for y in ans:
        if x % y == 0:
            break
    else: ans.append(x)
```

Edit: Promoting the [completion else](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_deep_python.html#completion-else).

Comment: This is much faster than the OP's approach because of the high cost of deleting elements from a list (compared to appending).

Comment: @AlainT. Well, if the input is a range starting from 2, then your method is actually faster, because using multiplication (implicit in `range`) is really efficient compared to mod. So I guess the answer for which is faster is "it depends".

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm will perform much faster:

```
A = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

if (A[-1]-A[0])/A[0] > len(A)*2:
    result = list()
    for v in A:
        for f in result:
            d,m = divmod(v,f)
            if m == 0: v=0;break
            if d<f: break
        if v: result.append(v)
else:        
    retain  = set(A)
    minMult = 1
    maxVal  = A[-1]
    for v in A:
        if v not in retain : continue
        minMult = v*2
        if minMult > maxVal: break         
        if v*len(A)<maxVal:
            retain.difference_update([m for m in retain if m >= minMult and m%v==0])
        else:
            retain.difference_update(range(minMult,maxVal,v))
        if maxVal%v == 0:
            maxVal  = max(retain)
    result = list(retain)

print(result) # [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```

In the spirit of the sieve of Eratostenes, each number that is retained, removes its multiples from the remaining eligible numbers.  Depending on the magnitude of the highest value, it is sometimes more efficient to exclude multiples than check for divisibility.  The divisibility check takes several times longer for an equivalent number of factors to check.

At some point, when the data is widely spread out, assembling the result instead of removing multiples becomes faster *(this last addition was inspired by  Imperishable Night's post)*.

**TEST RESULTS**

```
A = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16] (100000 repetitions)

Original: 0.55 sec
New:      0.29 sec


A = list(range(2,5000))+[9697] (100 repetitions)

Original: 3.77 sec
New:      0.12 sec


A = list(range(1001,2000))+list(range(4000,6000))+[9697**2] (10 repetitions)

Original: 3.54 sec
New:      0.02 sec
```

Comment: Try `A = list(range(2,5000))+[96970001]`. I get a `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`. (Changing to `result.difference_update([m for m in result if m >= minMult and m%v==0])` (notice the square brackets) solves the problem with no apparent performance loss.)

Comment: My bad, I guess I did one too many "beautifying" of the answer. I put the brackets back in now.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is totally insane but i want to know what you think about this:

```
A = [4,5,15,16,17,23,39]
prova=[[x for x in A if x!=y and y%x==0] for y in A]
print([A[idx] for idx,x in enumerate(prova) if len(prova[idx])==0])
```

And i think it's still O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

If you care about speed more than algorithmic efficiency, numpy would be the package to use here in python:

```
import numpy as np

# Note: doesn't have to be sorted
a = [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 29, 29]

a = np.unique(a)

result = a[np.all((a % a[:, None] + np.diag(a)), axis=0)]

# array([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 29])
```

This divides all elements by all other elements and stores the remainder in a matrix, checks which columns contain only non-0 values (other than the diagonal), and selects all elements corresponding to those columns.

Comment: Yes that's worked but not way i wanted. You may help me with finding multiplicands of number from list faster

Comment: Have you tried this? In many cases (such as `A = list(range(2,5000))`), this is actually slower than most python implementations, since the actual number of mod operations needed is *much* less than `len(A) ** 2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is `O(n*M)` where M is the max size of an integer in your list. The integers are all assumed to be none negative. This also assumes your input list is sorted (came to that assumption since all lists you provided are sorted).

```
a = [4, 7, 7, 8]
# a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
# a = [4, 5, 15, 16, 17, 23, 39]

M = max(a)
used = set()
final_list = []

for e in a:
    if e in used:
        continue
    else:
        used.add(e)
        for i in range(e, M + 1):
            if not (i % e):
                used.add(i)
        final_list.append(e)

print(final_list)
```

Maybe this can be optimized even further...

If the list is not sorted then for the above method to work, one must sort it. The time complexity will then be `O(nlogn + Mn)` which equals to `O(nlogn)` when `n >> M`.

Comment: for a=[4, 7, 7, 8] ans must be [4, 7] but this is giving wrong ans [4, 7, 8]

Comment: @MeeTValani, thank you for pointing that out. Modified code to work. I am assuming the given list is sorted.